# Symfony2 Sonata Admin Error

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

I recently did a vendors/install and now my sonata admin is broken with the following error:

Item "roles" for "" does not exist in SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig at line 92

Here is the twig code:

```
{% if app.security %}
  {% for role in app.security.token.roles %}
    {% if not allowed %}
      {% set allowed = role.role == 'ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN' %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought but have you cleared your cache after vendors/install? `php app/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched through admin bundle with blame option and it comes from a commit 7 days ago

So what you have to do is go to deps.lock

Find the adminBundle commit hash(In my case it started with 4a....)
replace the hash with 25b401e6271ee0fd896d700d0328b06994e4e138 which is commit before the commit that cause problem

I tried it and dashboard works correctly

Good luck

***EDIT***

Be careful not to use php bin/vendor update since it will update the commit hash

Use php bin/vendor install

Comment: I didn't see the adminBundle in my list inside the deps.lock file

Comment: Well my bad adminBundle is the name I gave it so you should search for where you define the url of the sonata admin bundle repo

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix : https://github.com/Wiakowe/SonataAdminBundle/commit/e139527c05b22176ee3efab987ebe752668d4489

Remove lines 90-99 and replace with the following:

```
{% if app.security and is_granted('ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN') %}
```

Comment: I tried this and now I am receiving the following error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.") in SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig at line 90.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the last version of SonataAdminBundle. This problem appears if you allow for everybody opening your admin panel. This is not usuall solution at least for the working site.

To grant access to your admin panel for everybody do the following. Place the path **/admin** under firewall, add into the file **security.yml** in the section **security.firewals** the rows

```
    admin_area:
        pattern: ^/admin
        anonymous: ~
```

Thus each client will be authorized as **anonymous user** with existing token and the errors will not appear.

P.S. Sorry for grammar mistakes, but I think everybody will understand me :)